# Adaptive card version 1.5 Table is not rendering in the Bot Emulator

Tags: botframework

I am using a table of adaptive card version 1.5 but is not rendering into the emulator. My Emulator version is 4.14.1.
below is the JSON structure of the adaptive card.

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Table",
      "columns": [
        {
          "width": 1
        },
        {
          "width": 1
        },
        {
          "width": 1
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        {
          "type": "TableRow",
          "cells": [
            `yourtext`{
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "11",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "111",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "1111",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "TableRow",
          "cells": [
            {
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "22",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "222",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "2222",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "TableRow",
          "cells": [
            {
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "33",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "333",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "TableCell",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "3333",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bot Framework supports adaptive card version 1.3. So change Adaptive card "version": "1.5" to "version": "1.3"

Answer (score 0):

Bot Framework should now support 1.5, so this looks like a bug. As you reported it here:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/2407